# Using Php to connect a MySQL table to a Html page?

Tags: html, mysql

I'm trying to display a MySQL table onto a Html page, but there seems to be something wrong with the code. Here's what I have so far:

```
`<?php

 $db = mysql_connect("localhost","root",""); 
 if (!$db) {
 die("Database connection failed: " . mysql_error());
 }

 $db_select = mysql_select_db("test",$db);
 if (!$db_select) {
 die("Database selection also failed : " . mysql_error());
 }
?>
<html>
 <head>
 <title></title>
 </head>
 <body>
<div class="cssstyle">
 <?php

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table 1", $db);
 if (!$result) {
 die("Database query failed: " . mysql_error());
 }

 while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
 echo "<h2>";
 echo $row[1]."";
 echo "</h2>";
 echo "<p>";
 echo $row[2]."";
 echo "</p>";
 }
?>
</div>
 </body>
</html>

<?php

 mysql_close($db);
?>`
```

but I only recive this:

```
"; echo $row["MPN"].""; echo ""; echo "
"; echo $row["Model"].""; echo "

"; } ?>
```

Any ideas? Sorry I'm new to this coding thing

Comment: `echo "<h2>{$row[0]}</h2><p>{$row[1]}</p>";`

Comment: `table 1` is not a valid table name thus making query syntax invalid.

Answer (score 0):

I do not quite understand your error message, is that what is displayed on the webpage or what?

Firstly, are you sure your SQL query works? Usually SQL likes you to use ' ' around table names with space in them. In general bad idea to have spaces in table and field names. Use underscore or something like TabelName.

Now on to your PHP code: 
In PHP when using SQL you should use the field/variable names as indexes. 
So instead of writing:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
 echo "<h2>";
 echo $row[1]."";
 echo "</h2>";
 echo "<p>";
 echo $row[2]."";
 echo "</p>";
 }
```

You can write:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
 echo "<h2>";
 echo $row['MPN']."";
 echo "</h2>";
 echo "<p>";
 echo $row['Model']."";
 echo "</p>";
}
```

I assume your field names are 'MPN' and 'Model' in your database. 
To make your code more concise you can write:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
     echo "<h2>".$row['MPN'].".</h2> <p>".$row['Model']."</p>";
    }
```

However, got with what you find is easier to read. Hope this helps.